# Can’t review edit in pop up on mobile

Tags: bug, status-deferred, review, suggested-edits, responsive-design

I am using the full responsive site on mobile Safari (portrait orientation) and when I tap on “edit(1)” on a question’s page to review an edit, the pop up is unusable:

[image: extremely zoomed in]

I can’t go any more left but I can scroll right or down, although it’s so zoomed in I can’t see enough to easily review. There is no way to pinch zoom out.

Note that I can review from the queue because it’s not yet responsive, so I can see everything at once and pinch zoom in on anything I need to look closely at.

A possible temporary fix (before making it completely responsive) would be to make sure that the pop up shows up on screen (i.e. more right) and allow me to pinch zoom out to fit things horizontally.

Comment: Are you using an outdated phone or version of safari? Try updating, I don't have this problem.

Comment: @LemmyX I’m running a slightly outdated version of iOS 13 and idk what Safari; I thought that Safari was updated with the OS. In any case I’ll revisit this when I’m forced to update next.

Comment: We'll look into this as part of a larger project around mobile views and site responsiveness.