# "Add Original" button not reachable on mobile browser

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, mobile-chrome

If a question is closed as a duplicate (of one other question), and then if I try to edit it to add more duplicate questions, it's ok on a PC desktop browser.

However, on a mobile browser (Chrome on Android), it's impossible to add more original questions, because the dialog is larger than the screen, regardless of the screen orientation (vertical or horizontal).

The "Add Original" button is not reachable on the mobile browser.

## Desktop browser:

[image: desktop]

## Mobile browser (horizontal):

[image: horizontal]

## Mobile browser (vertical):

[image: vertical]

Comment: I had (different, but similar) problems with it before: [Editing the duplicate list doesn't really work on mobile with the new responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318115/295232)

Comment: I (now) use the workaround suggested in @Glorfindel's post. With your cursor in the box, you can submit the duplicate with the "return" (or "enter"?) button, which most mobile keyboards have.

Comment: @Laurel [this bug report of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346836/295232) is also related